# Customize ggplot2 legend with different variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data about American and German teenagers' coding skills. I can easily display their bar plots, but I need to present the total number of teenagers from each country as well.

```
DF <- data.frame(code = rep(c("A","B","C"), each = 2),
                 Freq = c(441,121,700,866,45,95),
                 Country = rep(c("USA","Germany"),3),
                 Total = rep(c(1186,1082),3))  

ggplot(DF, aes(code, Freq, fill = code)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = 0.7) + 
  facet_wrap(~Country, scales = "free") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

For example, instead of presenting the default legend for the `code`, I could replace it with the `Country` and the `Total`. Your help is appreciated

Comment: Please explain more. Would the legend relate to any particular variable being mapped?  It would seem more natural to me to change the facet header than to add a legend with Country totals.

Comment: @JonSpring If I remove the line of the code, the legend will be about the `code` variable (i.e. A green, B pink, C yellow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I would suggest:

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2)
DF %>%
  add_count(Country, wt = Total) %>%
  mutate(Country_total = paste0(Country, ": Total=", n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(code, Freq, fill = code)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = 0.7) + 
    facet_wrap(~Country_total, scales = "free") +
    theme_bw() +
    theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

To do what you're requesting would take a different approach, since the data you're describing would not strictly be a ggplot2 legend (which explains how one of the variables is mapped to one of the graph aesthetics), rather it would be a table or annotation that is displayed alongside the plot. This could be generated separately and added to the figure using `patchwork` or `grid` packages.

For instance:

```
library(patchwork); library(gridExtra)
ggplot(DF, aes(code, Freq, fill = code)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", alpha = 0.7) + 
  facet_wrap(~Country, scales = "free") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  tableGrob(count(DF, Country, wt = Total)) +
  plot_layout(widths = c(2,1))
```

[image]